# Code First Database Migration when swapping Azure Web App

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure, azure-web-app-service

Setup:

- Dev slot with slot setting to a DEV database
- Production slot with slot setting to a PRODUCTION database.

I enabled 'Execute Code First Migration' on my publish profile and publish onto the DEV slot. The DEV database gets updated perfectly.

But when swapping my slot to PROD the Code First Migration isn't being executed on the PROD database.

We have multiple customers that need this setup. I want developers to setup the new version onto the DEV slot and I want my project managers to SWAP it when they feel the customer is ready to receive the new version and this way they can demo the new version immediately. I don't want them doing any more additional actions.

For now I have made a fix that makes them browse to an URL in the app that will execute any missing updates via the following piece of code:

```
var configuration = new Configuration();
var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
migrator.Update();
```

It is normal that the migration isn't getting triggered when swapping the slots?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the connection string configured as a slot-specific setting?  If so your worker process should restart on swap.  And you just need to ensure migrations run on startup.  Apparently the configuration changes made by the publishing profile to cause migration to run on startup aren't propagated into the production slot.

See this post on the ASP.NET blog for options: [EF Code First Migrations Deployment to an Azure Cloud Service](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/04/08/ef-code-first-migrations-deployment-to-an-azure-cloud-service/)

Comment: Yes, both have a connection string with slot setting enabled.